# How to extract from list and tuples

Tags: python, list

I query data from database from one colomn and I want use them but I do know how to extract them.

```
[(725696042,), (706284799,), (705263536,), (706705005,)]
```

I what to get the results like this

`725696042, 706284799, 705263536, 706705005`

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: I guess the  query itself could be modified to get your expected result in the first place

Comment: You need from list of tuples to tuple. Try this : `tuple(i[0] for i in list_)`

Comment: You should first learn the basic of the prog lang that you will use (you ll find directly the answer), then you must give it some tries before calling for help..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a flat list out of list of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

```
list1 = [(725696042,), (706284799,), (705263536,), (706705005,)]
list2 = []
for i in list1:
    list2.append(i[0])

print(list2)
```

Output:

```
[725696042, 706284799, 705263536, 706705005]
```

Comment: Thanks so much this answer have helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I get you right but this is what i understood:

```
a = [(725696042,), (706284799,), (705263536,), (706705005,)]

a[0] = (725696042,)
a[0][0] = 725696042
a[1] = (706284799,)
a[1][0] = 706284799
....
```

This way you can access your elements to extract values

Comment: Instead of going thru the pain of parsing the data, the op may adjust his query to get their expected result directly. In that perspective, the question looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)